# Can not authenticate via mongo's official node.js driver, only mongo shell. (MongoDB Cloud Manager replica deployment)

Tags: mongodb, authentication, driver, replicaset, database

I am trying to authenticate to my replica set, which was deployed via Mongo Cloud Manager, but I can not figure out why it fails.

Here are my users on database **abcd**:

```
abcdRepliaSet:PRIMARY> use abcd
switched to db abcd
show users
abcdRepliaSet:PRIMARY> show users
{
 "_id" : "abcd.abcdAppUser",
 "user" : "abcdAppUser",
 "db" : "abcd",
 "roles" : [
 {
 "role" : "readWrite",
 "db" : "abcd"
 }
 ]
}
```

and I can successfully connect to it via mongo shell:

```
mongo adbcd-mongo-mms.cloudapp.net:57002 -u adbcd AppUser -p hidden --authenticationDatabase adbcd
```

However, I can not using this simple code:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://abcdAppUser:hidden@abcd-mongo-mms.cloudapp.net:57001,abcd-mongo-mms.cloudapp.net:57002,abcd-mongo-mms.cloudapp.net:57003/abcd?replicaSet=abcdRepliaSet&authSource=abcd&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1",
 function(err, db) {
 if(err) throw err;
 else console.log(db);
});
```

I am also pretty sure my authMechanism is SCRAM-SHA-1 as I've added the user using mongoldb v. 3.0.7 and I've also confirmed it using:

```
db.system.users.find({user:"abcdAppUser"}).pretty()
```

Here is mongod's log when I try to auth via the nodejs app:

```
2015-12-22T13:31:33.823+0000 I ACCESS   [conn30286] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for abcdAppUser on abcd from client 10.0.0.10 ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2015-12-22T13:31:33.894+0000 I ACCESS   [conn30288] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for abcdAppUser on abcd from client 10.0.0.10 ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2015-12-22T13:31:34.051+0000 I ACCESS   [conn30287] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for abcdAppUser on abcd from client 10.0.0.10 ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2015-12-22T13:31:34.124+0000 I ACCESS   [conn30289] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for abcdAppUser on abcd from client 10.0.0.10 ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2015-12-22T13:31:34.206+0000 I ACCESS   [conn30290] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for abcdAppUser on abcd from client 10.0.0.10 ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch
2015-12-22T13:31:34.263+0000 I NETWORK  [conn30288] end connection 94.61.85.76:53102 (17 connections now open)
2015-12-22T13:31:34.264+0000 I NETWORK  [conn30286] end connection 94.61.85.76:61293 (17 connections now open)
2015-12-22T13:31:34.263+0000 I NETWORK  [conn30287] end connection 94.61.85.76:58194 (17 connections now open)
2015-12-22T13:31:34.263+0000 I NETWORK  [conn30289] end connection 94.61.85.76:58537 (17 connections now open)
2015-12-22T13:31:34.264+0000 I NETWORK  [conn30290] end connection 94.61.85.76:57720 (13 connections now open)
2015-12-22T13:31:37.185+0000 I NETWORK  [conn30281] end connection 10.0.0.8:34322 (12 connections now open)
```

I also made sure my node.js driver was compatible with SCRAM and it is. At this point, I can't really understand why it fails... Any help would be most welcome!

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Pedro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what I did wrong, but I've now upgraded the authSchema (pretty sure it was already on v.5, anyways), deleted the same user, and added it back again with the exact same password and roles. It now works. Go figure... Also, this might have been due to https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-scram/#upgrade-mongodb-cr-to-scram but I'm not sure as I've now idea what version was installed before (dev environment, so excuse me the lack of proper logging :P)

Anyway, thought this answer would eventually help someone in the future...